# What is the dimension of $Aut(G)$ where $G$ is a Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, gauge-theory

This question is inspired from a physics question. I understand that gauge groups are the automorphism groups of structure groups (which are finite-dimensional Lie groups).

Consider a right Principal $G$-Bundle $\pi:P\to \mathfrak{M}_4$ and the group ${\cal G} = \Gamma(P\times_G G)$ of global sections of the associated bundle $ P\times_G G$.

Is it true that ${\cal G}$ is isomorphic to the group of (inner?) automorphisms of $G$? Assuming that ${\cal G}= Aut(G)$, then the dimensionality of $Aut(G)$ should be infinite.

What am I missing?

Comment: Leaving this as a comment instead of an answer because I don't know anything about physics, but in general the outer automorphisms of a Lie group are a finite group, and the inner automorphisms are $G$ mod the center, so finite dimensional.

Comment: $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ has nothing to do with $\Gamma(P\times_GG)$. I think you are confusing it with $\mathrm{Aut}(P)$, which indeed can be identified with $\Gamma(P\times_GG)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ that is isomorphic to $\Gamma(P\times_GG)$; its $\mathrm{Aut}(P)$. (For one thing $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a finite-dimensional Lie group when $G$ is a compact Lie group.)

The isomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(P)\cong\Gamma(P\times_GG)$ can be viewed as follows. Recall that an element $\varphi\in\mathrm{Aut}(P)$ is a bundle homomorphism $\varphi:P\to P$ covering the identity on the base space. Thus, for all $p\in P$ we have $\varphi(p)=p\cdot\psi(p)$ where $\psi$ is some smooth function $\psi:P\to G$ that is equivariant: $\psi(p\cdot g)=g^{-1}\psi(p)g$. Now, we can define
$$P\to P\times_GG,\quad p\mapsto(p,\psi(p))$$
and by equivariance of $\psi$ this descends to a section
$$\sigma_\varphi:M\to P\times_GG.$$
Now, it is not hard to show that the assignment
$$\mathrm{Aut}(P)\to \Gamma(P\times_GG),\quad\varphi\mapsto\sigma_\varphi$$
is a well-defined bijection.

Comment: If $P$ is the trivial bundle, would that mean $Aut(P)$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: @J.Rahman No. If $P$ is trivial (i.e. $P=M\times G$) then $\mathrm{Aut}(P)=C^\infty(M,G)$, the space of smooth functions $M\to G$. This is infinite-dimensional.